# Any source code for connecting a tinyshield to another tinyshield?

Tags: bluetooth

I recently purchase 2 tinycircuit smart watch. I am wondering if anyone knows if there is any source code for me to reference on how do I connect one tinyshield to another tinyshield. I understand that a tinyshield is both a master and slave. I am trying to connect 2 tinyshield to each other such that I could transmit data between those two tinyshield.

Currently, when I upload the code into two tinyshield, the receiving tinyshield can't seem to be receving any thing, while the sender tinyshield is sending over data

## Sender code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    Serial.print("connecting"); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }
    mySerial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int vert = 200;
  int LDRReading = 100;
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("LDR : "); 
  Serial.print(LDRReading);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(" acc: ");
  Serial.println(vert);
  sendData(LDRReading, vert);
}

void sendData(int ldr, int accel)
{
    mySerial.write(((ldr >> 7) & 0x7F) | 0x80); // Upper 7 bytes and first bit
    mySerial.write(ldr & 0x7F); // Lower 7 bytes
    mySerial.write((accel >> 7) & 0x7F); // Upper 7 bytes
    mySerial.write(accel & 0x7F); // Lower 7 bytes
}
```

## Receiver Code

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    }
    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int result=0,acc=0;
if (getDataFromSerial(&result, &acc))
{
    // use accel and ldr
}
  if(result!=0&&acc!=0){
    Serial.print(result);
    Serial.print(acc);
  }
  
}

boolean getDataFromSerial(int *p_ldr, int *p_accel)
{
    boolean foundData = false;

    while ((!foundData) && (mySerial.available() >= 4))
    {
        if (!(mySerial.peek() & 0x80))
        { // If the first byte in the buffer is not a valid start, discard it
            mySerial.read();
            continue;
        }

        *p_ldr = mySerial.read() & 0x7F;
        *p_ldr = ((*p_ldr) << 7) | (mySerial.read() & 0x7F);
        if ((*p_ldr) & 0x2000) (*p_ldr) |= 0xC000; // This is the sign extension

        *p_accel = mySerial.read() & 0x7F;
        *p_accel = ((*p_accel) << 7) | (mySerial.read() & 0x7F);
        if ((*p_accel) & 0x2000) (*p_accel) |= 0xC000; // This is the sign extension

        foundData = true;
        }
         return foundData;
    }
```

Comment: That depends on the shields, that you are using. As I understood from the [Tinycircuits product page](https://tinycircuits.com/pages/tinyduino-overview) the modules need different communication methods. Some use Serial, some SPI and others I2C. Please give us more details and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried connecting the tinyshield to tinyshield via serial to serial.

Comment: 1. Please put all new information into your question by editing it. We are trying to build a coherent Q&A database to help others. 2. We still need more information. Are you trying to connect 2 master shields (those with the Atmega328p on them), or different shields? And what have you tried so far? There are tons of Serial code out there and the chip is the same as in the Arduino Uno and Nano, so you can reuse many of them.

Comment: My apology, I have edited my question and included my codes for what I have try.

Comment: `while (!Serial)  Serial.print("Who's writing this ?");` looks a bit silly (or like a philosophical paradoxon) to me :)

Comment: Besides connecting Rx-Tx and Tx-Rx you have to connect both GND too. (Just in case)

Comment: Have you tried to simply immediately send all data received from Software Serial over Serial? That would show, if the data actually get's read. Currently you are doing a lot with the data, before actually sending it, including discarding data. You should first look, if the correct data get's received correctly